# Update primary key - if duplicate, then delete it

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update, duplicates

I am trying to remove the whitespace from my primary key column like so:

```
update EMAILS set email = TRIM(email);
```

However, in the case that the trimmed email is a duplicate, I want to simply delete it. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a great way to do what you suggest in a single query as MySQL is not really designed to accommodate a case like this where the initial primary key data was not properly sanitized before being inserted in the first place.

My suggestion would be to perform a separate query before this update that would identify and remove these potential records.  You could do that like this:

```
DELETE
FROM emails AS delete
INNER JOIN emails AS original
   ON TRIM(delete.email) = original.email
   AND delete.email <> original.email
```

This would remove all those rows from the table that when trimmed would result in a primary key conflict.  This query may take a while to run depending on the size of your table, since you would not be able to leverage an index for the `TRIM()`-based JOIN criteria.